# ArcPy and File Geodatabase Character Encoding

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, file-geodatabase, python-2.7, unicode

I have a JSON file containing special characters, which can be represented in Unicode. However, as soon as I export that JSON file to a file geodatabase using arcpy, the special characters all "break," i.e., they come out as something different. A Google search tells me (via [this table](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=128&number=128&utf8=string-literal&unicodeinhtml=hex) listing string representations of special characters) that the character I'm having a problem with in my sample dataset is in UTF-8/Latin-1.

The code I'm using for this is:

```
arcpy.JSONToFeatures_conversion(jsonFileName, os.path.join(fgdbPath, outputName))
```

I have also specified the encoding for the Python (2.7) file via:

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```

I have also varied the above with "latin-1" and various other specifications for the encoding, mostly experimentally as I have little experience with encoding.

But regardless, where the content of my JSON file is for example **"Búzi",** the content of my feature (exported to an FGDB) will be **"BÃºzi".**

Nowhere can I find out about a parameter to pass to JSONToFeatures_conversion, or to CreateFileGDB_management (where I create the FGDB in question), or an Arc environment variable to set, which will allow me to specify the desired encoding.

How do I export to FGDB with the desired encoding (or providing the desired result by whatever means)?

Comment: Does this not address it?
http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#//003n00000021000000

Comment: can you share your json file and check gdb config key. If your json is not encode in utf-8 sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8') dont change the problem. you need rencode json file to utf8 before the conversion

Comment: The contents of the JSON file are correct. If you need to verify this, where can I share the file? I assume copy/pasting the JSON contents is not sufficient to determine if the encoding is correct? Also, the configuration keyword would probably solve this, but how can it be set for the FGDB using arcpy?

Comment: Use share data service and add source script and json.txt or data source link. It easiest to check problem and find solution

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Please send a link to the site you want me to use.

Comment: How's this?
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8Ci6I3DqsILYVBzNG9nUFV2U3M/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I have same error. I check with different params: new gdb  with arcpy.env.configKeyword = "TEXT_UTF16" ; add  arcpy.env.configKeyword = "TEXT_UTF16" in for workspace in script... No change. I have already check in *.mdb but there is same result. Can you test with insert cursor with a table?

Comment: If the JSON is not UTF-8 compliant, the string must be repaired **BEFORE** it is passed to ArcGIS.  *Changing the internal storage representation will have no impact if the external representation is corrupt*

Comment: @Vince If, but it is valid utf-8. I have check with other encoding conversion. This caracter is reencoded in utf-8 in insertion process. I don't understand why. I would do new test tomorrow with an other file.

Comment: @GeoStoneMarten That's a good idea. I can try to unpack the JSON into a dictionary, create a blank table and insert the data with a cursor. I was avoiding that until now, in case there was a simpler solution...

Comment: Just to keep you all in the loop: I'm going to ask ESRI themselves to take a look at this, since doing it with a cursor (even if it works) is not so great for efficiency - and handling special characters by default is probably a function that their software should support anyway. In the meantime I'm going to try to ASCII-fy special characters with [Unidecode](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode/0.04.1), but that's obviously not a permanent solution.

Comment: @WolfieInu  For test you can just create loop on char string to insert you special characters one by one with cursor in table contain just one text field. If it work, problem is not the file but process (env param of function).

Comment: @Vince what jargon you used-Please-Please clarify- i converted above json to to utf-8-sig but with vain rather got a message `001558 : Error parsing .json file <value>.` where simple command works fantastic `ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" destination_data.shp "Roads_20151130_133158.json"`

Comment: @SIslam Vince was just saying that if the encoding isn't correct in the JSON file, then trying to convert to the correct encoding after the error occurs will not fix the incorrect data.

Comment: Yes i changed the `encoding` into utf-8 even unicode i.e. `u` pre-eneded but with vain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an answer from ESRI, basically even though it seemed like the JSON was coming off the server correctly (via a REST URL), it was getting encoded incorrectly while being read. I used to do it this way:

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

# later...
jsonResponse = urllib2.urlopen(jsonRequest)
jsonFile = codecs.open(jsonFileName, 'w', 'utf-8')
jsonFile.write(str(jsonResponse.read()))
jsonFile.close()
```

Even though there was a string conversion to prevent errors while writing the response to a file, I did specify the default encoding and assumed that this took care of the problem, since the encoding seemed correct when opening the saved JSON file in Notepad. However, it turns out that Notepad was being too clever for itself and doing some implicit conversions or something, because writing the JSON file with a different method solved the problem, so obviously my string conversion was a stupid thing to do.

The solution provided by ESRI was:

```
jsonResponse = urllib2.urlopen(jsonRequest)
with io.open(jsonFileName, 'w') as jsonFile:
    jsonFile.write(
        ''.join([i.decode('utf-8') for i in jsonResponse.readlines()]))
```